# Is a graph with four vertices of degrees 1, 2, 3, and 3 possible?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I know there are some rules about the number of vertices and degrees of a graph, and whether it's possible, but I'm not sure which rule applies here.  I don't think this graph is possible, but I could be mistaken.

I think this has something to do with the sum of the degrees of each vertex being 9, which is odd, but I'm not positive what I should be looking for.

Comment: It does have to do with the sum of the degrees being odd.  What do you know about the sum of the degrees in relation to the number of edges?

Comment: Should the sum of degrees be twice the number of edges?

Comment: Not twice the number of vertices, but instead twice the number of edges.  Read more on [the handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma).

Comment: @JMoravitz Yup I just corrected myself, I miswrote it.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

> For any simple graph $G=(V,E)$ $$\sum_{v\in V} \deg(v) = 2|E|$$

The right hand side is an even number.  What does that imply about the number of odd degree vertices in the graph?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [handshake lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma). $$\sum_{v \in V}\mathrm{deg(v)} = 2 |E|$$ In our context, $\sum_{v\in V}\mathrm{deg(v)} = 1 + 2+ 3 + 3 = 9$.

Now you want $9 = 2|E|$. But there is no integer $|E|$ to satisfy this equation -- $9$ is odd, and any $2|E|$ will be even.

So it's impossible.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks for catching that. I've corrected my answer. It remains impossible.